# Using pandas to sum numerical differences in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking at the MTA turnstile data for New York City subways and I'm trying to find out what the total traffic is for each station. Each station has a number of unique turnstiles and both entries and exits are counted. I want to sum the entries and exits for each station to determine the traffic for a given period of time.

A unique turnstile is determined by a combination of the ID in the SCP column and the name in the STATION column. The turnstile traffic numbers are cumulative so for a given time frame (say a day) you need to find the starting value, subtract it from the ending value and sum up all of these differences for each turnstile at a station to get the traffic for the station.

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
    C/A    UNIT        SCP   STATION    LINENAME    DIVISION    DATE TIME   DESC    ENTRIES EXITS   NEW_DATE
0   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 04/28/2018  00:00:00    REGULAR 6598847 2235829 2018-04-28
1   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 04/28/2018  04:00:00    REGULAR 6598864 2235830 2018-04-28
2   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 04/28/2018  08:00:00    REGULAR 6598880 2235863 2018-04-28
3   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 04/28/2018  12:00:00    REGULAR 6598961 2235955 2018-04-28
4   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 04/28/2018  16:00:00    REGULAR 6599175 2236015 2018-04-28
```

So far I've tried varying combinations of `df.groupby(['SCP', 'STATION'])`, but I can't quite figure out how to properly groupby or apply other methods to produce the result of the summed differences per station.

I'd like to be able to generate outputs for various time frames. Here is an example of the output I'd like for a single day:

```
STATION   | DATE                | ENTRIES | EXITS | TOTALS |     
CHURCH AV | 2018-04-28 00:00:00 | 12948   | 9076  | 22024  |
59 ST     | 2018-04-28 00:00:00 | 20401   | 17907 | 38308  |
```

Note that the ENTRIES and EXITS do not start from 0, but have been cumulative over time so the first two entries in the data set looks like the below. Note that I am masking (...)  non-important columns here for the sake of readability:

```
...  |   SCP   | STATION | ... |    DATE     |   TIME   | ...   | ENTRIES | EXITS  |
...  |02-00-00 | 59 ST   | ... |  2018-04-28 | 00:00:00 | ...   | 6598847 | 2235829|
...  |02-00-00 | 59 ST   | ... |  2018-04-28 | 04:00:00 | ...   | 6598864 | 2235830|
```

Adding the code I've used up to this point. I'm also adding one of the data sources that I'm using:

```
    # Importing and cleaning data
    may05_2018 = pd.read_csv('http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_180505.txt')

    # Only including one of the several files for this example
    source_data = [may05_2018] 

    # Clean data
    all_converted_data = []
    for i in source_data:
        converted = i 
        converted['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(i['DATE'] + ' ' + i['TIME'])
        converted.drop('TIME', axis=1, inplace=True)
        converted.rename(columns = lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)   
        all_converted_data.append(converted)

    # Create copy of data frame to maintain the original
    test_df = df.copy()

    # Function for calculating differences
    def mta_traffic(data, freq='D'):
        data.ENTRIES = data.ENTRIES - data.shift(1).ENTRIES
        data.EXITS = data.EXITS - data.shift(1).EXITS
        data = data.set_index(['STATION', 'SCP'])[['ENTRIES', 'EXITS', 'DATE']]
        data = data.resample(freq, on='DATE').sum()
        return data

    # Create df of data sums. These seem to generate legit values.
    test_df = test_df.groupby(['STATION', 'SCP']).apply(mta_traffic)

    # Add TOTALS column, the sum of ENTRIES and EXITS
    test_df['TOTALS'] = test_df['ENTRIES'] + test_df['EXITS']

    # Attempt to groupby STATION and find the sums per station
    station_traffic = test_df.groupby('STATION')['TOTALS'].sum()
```

**OUT**

```
    STATION
    1 AV               2.135754e+06
    103 ST             4.971873e+08
    103 ST-CORONA      1.528737e+06
    104 ST            -5.682778e+09
    110 ST             9.083200e+05
    111 ST             3.939572e+07
    116 ST            -3.635802e+09
```

And that's where the values go kind of crazy. Some seem like they may be legit, but others, like the negative ones, are definitely wrong.

Right now I'm trying to figure out why grouping by STATION on the result is generating bad values, while non-grouped results seem to be fine. Again, ultimately I want to output the per-STATION traffic during different time frames and intervals.

Comment: Can you add expected output? Maybe also help create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated the question. Hopefully this is a bit more helpful. I hadn't really gotten close to a good answer, so I don't think adding code and the result will be productive at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Data example:

```
        SCP STATION        DATE      TIME  ENTRIES   EXISTS    NEW_DATE
0  02-00-00   59 ST  04/28/2018  00:00:00  6598847  2235829  2018-04-28
1  02-00-00   59 ST  04/28/2018  04:00:00  6598864  2235830  2018-04-28
2  02-00-00   59 ST  04/28/2018  08:00:00  6598880  2235863  2018-04-28
3  02-00-00   59 ST  04/28/2018  12:00:00  6598961  2235955  2018-04-28
4  02-00-00   59 ST  04/28/2018  16:00:00  6599175  2236015  2018-04-28
```

I recommend do this to have dates in a good representation:

```
series.DATE = pd.to_datetime(series.DATE) + pd.to_timedelta(series.TIME)

series = series.drop(['TIME', 'NEW_DATE'], 1)
```

**Out:**

```
        SCP STATION                DATE  ENTRIES   EXISTS
0  02-00-00   59 ST 2018-04-28 00:00:00  6598847  2235829
1  02-00-00   59 ST 2018-04-28 04:00:00  6598864  2235830
2  02-00-00   59 ST 2018-04-28 08:00:00  6598880  2235863
3  02-00-00   59 ST 2018-04-28 12:00:00  6598961  2235955
4  02-00-00   59 ST 2018-04-28 16:00:00  6599175  2236015
```

To do what you want with grouped data you can define your function, like:

```
def function(series, freq='D'):
    series.ENTRIES = series.ENTRIES - series.shift(1).ENTRIES
    series.EXISTS = series.EXISTS - series.shift(1).EXISTS
    series = series.set_index(['SCP', 'STATION'])[['ENTRIES', 'EXISTS', 'DATE']]
    series = series.resample(freq, on='DATE').sum()
    return series
```

And then use it with groupby:

```
series.groupby(['SCP','STATION']).apply(function)
```

**Out:**

```
                             ENTRIES  EXISTS
SCP      STATION DATE                       
02-00-00 59 ST   2018-04-28    328.0   186.0
```

(here first 3 columns is index)

Also you can pass arguments (example you want to have 3 hour frequency):

```
series.groupby(['SCP','STATION']).apply(function, freq='3H')
```

**Out:**

```
                                      ENTRIES  EXISTS
SCP      STATION DATE                                
02-00-00 59 ST   2018-04-28 00:00:00      0.0     0.0
                 2018-04-28 03:00:00     17.0     1.0
                 2018-04-28 06:00:00     16.0    33.0
                 2018-04-28 09:00:00      0.0     0.0
                 2018-04-28 12:00:00     81.0    92.0
                 2018-04-28 15:00:00    214.0    60.0
```

But with this example be careful in first raw. In function I use shift, to subtract with previous raw (I don't know how your data looks in start, so we have `NaN` for first raw, because it doesn't have a previous raw).

Comment: Thanks Anna! I think this gets most of the way there, but I am getting some weird results. The numbers in the first row for ENTRIES and EXITS is 852513406.0 and 1.575377e+09, which are way outside the range of values we should be getting. The second row is 22383.0 and 1.819800e+4 which seems more reasonable. However, I'm also getting negative values at the beginning of each week. 

Any idea why that might be? I updated my question with a bit more detail.

Comment: @T.Rettig could you post example with problem data? Or generate simple data example with the same problem.

Comment: @T.Retting well, I think I know what's the problem. But I can try and write about this only through 10 hours = )

Comment: Thanks again. I updated the question with more info and a link to a portion of the data set I'm using.